# What RGB Led to use to light PC

Tags: led, modding

I recently build my first pc. I have no RGB lighting in it, didn't want it at the time to look like a circus.

But I do have some components that light up. I want to light up the whole a bit more with a RGB LED strip. My motherboard supports RGB lighting (it's an [ASRock Z370 Killer SLI](https://www.asrock.com/MB/Intel/Z370%20Killer%20SLIac/index.asp))

My question is, can I just buy any RGB led strip for modding? So is this a standard connection or do I need to look for a specific ASRock LED strip?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Its in the [manual](https://www.asrock.com/MB/Intel/Z370%20Killer%20SLIac/index.asp#Manual) - page 44 on the english version.

[image]

Good news is they use *very* standard 5050 LED strips. These refer to a specific size but are otherwise mostly generic. 5050s are preferred here since they have 3 chips per package so you can have all 3 colours in a chip.

You don't need/want the addressable flavour of them (WS something or another) - these are costlier, and not compatible , and waterproof versions are probably a little more than you need (tho a little nicer for straight lengths of lighting).You can *typically* buy a set of them off your preferred online vendor for not much money.

These are often sold with connectors, and a little remote/control unit (and you can get extra ones) and typically can be cut to length with solderable tabs every 3 LEDs, or get extentions. Just remember these things are *not* registered (typically its just a header) and need to be plugged in the right way. As of 2017, I'd suspect a 5m roll of the stuff would be under a tenner.

Comment: I should've looked into the manual thanks for your extra information!

Comment: Amusingly, I'm currently looking at (white) LEDs for a completely different project - so I had the additional information off the top of my head. If you get a roll of the stuff, you'd probably be able to just plug it into your header to test. I'd actually recommend getting the kit with the remote, and picking up connectors and extenders as you work out what you need.